# Spring Call Remote EJB on Weblogic 8.1

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

I am trying to connect to a legacy system using spring in our new osgi container, and I am running into the following exception:

> java.lang.Exception: Unable to convert value org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean@310a250a to type com.company.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandler

This is the class I have set up to inject the `counterpartyHandler` bean into via spring:

```
import com.company.cpm.domain.Counterparty;
import com.company.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandler;

public class CpmDataRetriever {
    private CounterpartyHandler counterpartyHandler;

    public void setCounterpartyHandler(CounterpartyHandler counterpartyHandler) {
        this.counterpartyHandler = counterpartyHandler;
    }

    public Counterparty getCounterparty()
    {
        // TODO: implement function
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is my spring configuration:

```
<!-- set up cpm data retriever bean -->
<bean id="counterpartyHandler"
      class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="com.company.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandlerHome" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.company.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandler"/>
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://someserver.domain.com:41700</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cpmDataRetriever" class="com.company.fuse.esb.cpm.CpmDataRetriever">
    <property name="counterpartyHandler" ref="counterpartyHandler" />
</bean>
```

And here is the ejb-jar.xml:

```
<ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>CounterpartyHandler</ejb-name>
            <home>com.company.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandlerHome</home>
            <remote>com.company.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandler</remote>
            <ejb-class>com.company.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandlerBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

My question is why is it trying to convert the `SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean` to my business interface `CounterpartyHandler`? Shouldn't it be using the factory to wire up the business interface to the bean via the home interface? Or am I missing something completely?

**EDIT**

To clarify here is the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml as well which includes the jndi name I am trying to resolve:

```
<weblogic-ejb-jar>
    <!-- CounterpartyHandler -->
    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>CounterpartyHandler</ejb-name>
        <stateless-session-descriptor>
            <pool>
                <max-beans-in-free-pool>5</max-beans-in-free-pool>
                <initial-beans-in-free-pool>0</initial-beans-in-free-pool>
            </pool>
        </stateless-session-descriptor>
        <jndi-name>com.dteco.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandlerHome</jndi-name>
    </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing your `jndiName`. That seems like your `homeInterface` not your jndiName. This forum post may help a little: http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/ejb/58414-ejb-remote-interface-binding-through-business-delegate

Comment: @castling thanks I'll take a look at that. In the mean time I have included also the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml file which shows the `jndi-name` value as `com.dteco.cpm.process.CounterpartyHandlerHome`